# Restrict input with max length

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework

I need to have an input boxes that only accepts hex characters and need to supply a max length.

I am able to handle accepting hex only but where I am having issues with is when I paste a string - the invalid characters are being counted as well in the max length.

Here is what I currently have:

```
<q-input outlined v-model="text" label="Outlined" @input="acceptHexOnly" maxlength="6"></q-input>
```

And:

```
acceptHexOnly () {
  console.log(this.text)
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.text = this.text.replace(/[^a-fA-F0-9\n\r]+/g, '').toUpperCase()
  })
}
```

So when pasting string:

```
xabx12xcdxef
```

- Expected: `AB12CD`
- Actual: `AB12`

Help!

Fiddle:
https://codepen.io/keechan/pen/qBZoXPj

Comment: because `xabx12` is 6 long - your replace happens those characters only - as you can see in the `console.log(this.text)`

Comment: Yes I understand that. But how can I be able to handle an input box that would accept 6 'correct' characters?

Comment: don't limit the length using maxlength ... limit the length using, maybe `this.text = this.text.replace(/[^a-fA-F0-9\n\r]+/g, '').toUpperCase().slice(0,6)`

Comment: That works for me! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks! @JaromandaX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the maxlength property from the input field and add the .slice(0, 6) as follows

```
acceptHexOnly () {
  console.log(this.text)
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.text = this.text.replace(/[^a-fA-F0-9\n\r]+/g, '').toUpperCase().slice(0, 6)
  })
}
```